# Album Rotator with persistent information

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, flash

I have a design in mind, i have added an image here ---> [image]

I would like to have those squares in the middle as album covers, and the ability to rotate them then have the text box below it, contain information about that album. Can someone point me in the right direction? I suppose i could use any JQuery,Flash or Javascript to do the slider, but how would i make the information change without the page refreshing? I've heard AJAX can help with this? I'm unfamiliar with AJAX however, and i'm fairly new to web development.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why AJAX ? you don't need it. When you create your slider (using JS or Flash ... ) you attach the text information with each slide and then when showing the slide you show attached text in the zone at the bottom.

Comment: that's all fine and dandy but i don't know how to make it show the text at the bottom

Comment: That depends on slider component used. If you have already implemented one, we can probably help you.